# Inline-Block alignment center

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a table with many sentences where the words are broken up into their own cells something like the following.  *Each word has their own cell to add clickable buttons.

Row 1 This is a pen (Centers fine with inline-block)

But any time there are more cells than can fit on a row it automatically goes down to the next line and aligns LEFT!

Row 2

This is a very nice looking

pen

Row 3

These are very excellent

amazing pens.

I want to get results with centering.

This is a very long

```
   pencil
```

Comment: What's the current code you are using to display the words in cells and center aligned?

Comment: You need to edit the question and add the code there. And also the code you shared is not enough to understand what you are doing and what the issue you are facing.

Comment: Code is complex.  I just wanted to know the concept and 1 line of code...I figured out it was using contain and wrapper but text-align center was the key.

Answer (score 0):

Put text-align: center; in DIV to make it center.